# How to execute a Ruby file in Java?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I am trying to run Ruby code using Java. This code gives me an empty result. 
(result: null)
Could any one please help me finding the error?

Java :

```
    public static void callRuby(){

      ScriptEngine jruby = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("jruby");
        //process a ruby file
        try {           
             jruby.eval(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("rubyTest.rb")));
             jruby.put("a", "2");
             jruby.put("b", "3");   
             System.out.println("result: " +jruby.get("res"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

rubyTest.rb

```
def addition(a,b)
puts a
puts b
res = a + b
end
```

Comment: did you try calling put() before eval() ?

Comment: I'm not sure it works this way, since res is a local variable that the ScriptEngine knows nothing about... try to return the value from the function and print what eval() returns...

Answer (score 2):

Your `rubyTest.rb` script defines a function, `addition(a, b)`, but where do you ever *call* that function?

This defines the function in the interpreter:

```
jruby.eval(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("rubyTest.rb")));
```

Then you assign top-level variables `a` and `b`, and then you ask for the value of `res`, but I don't see anywhere where your program calls the `addition(a,b)` function.

Comment: can you tell me please,how can i call the addition(a,b)?

Comment: Do you know Ruby?  If not, time to learn.  https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/  Basically, you can either add the call at the end of your script file, or you can use `jruby.eval(...)` to evaluate a Ruby expression that calls the function.  I haven't personally used JRuby from within a Java program, so I don't know the exact details.  _Maybe_ just as simple as `jruby.eval("addition(a,b)");`

Answer (score 0):

James Answer contains already the solution.

It's just as simple as `jruby.eval("addition(2,3)");`

If you really need to work with variables `a, b` you can make them global (with all the sideeffects of global variables) `$a, $b` and assign the values like that

```
 jruby.eval("$a = 2");
 jruby.eval("$b = 3");
 System.out.println("result: " + jruby.eval("addition($a,$b)"));
```

The Bindings mechanism of Java Scripting seem not to work as the following code **FAILS**:

```
 Bindings bindings = jruby.createBindings();
 bindings.put("a", 2);
 bindings.put("a", 3);
 // variation A
 System.out.println("result: " + jruby.eval("addition(a,b)", bindings));

 // variation B
 jruby.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
 System.out.println("result: " + jruby.eval("addition(a,b)"));
```